# HTML fIeld with datetime ticks

Tags: html, datetime

I'm calling a webservice through Ajax that only accepts datetime parameters as a 'long' type (representing the ticks).

Is there anyway to have a datetime input field on a form that represents this?

I would like to have a Date and Time selector (with a calendar and those kind of eye candy) that internally send the field value (or at least exposes the value) as Ticks.

Comment: The only native thing you're going to find is the `<input type="date">`, but it only does part of your job, and isn't supported by every web browsers (FF doesn't support it). You should get searching for a JS library answering your concerns.

Comment: as far I checked, only Google Chrome supports native `<input type='date'>`. You can use `Date()` from javascript to create a date object and pass date/time through it! get `Date()` tutorial [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume by "ticks" you mean milliseconds since epoch.  You could use an existing plugin like http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/.  It supports both date and time pickers.  From there, simply grab the value and run it through new Date('supported format here').getTime() to get the milliseconds value.  If you're looking for a pure HTML5 way, unfortunately that isn't possible.